# HTML5 drag and drop file upload to Java Servlet

Tags: html, servlets, file-upload, drag-and-drop

I am currently using Uploadify (Flash + Ajax) to the Servlet (Commons Upload with OWASP ESAPI overlay) with success, but I was wondering how I would go about building in HTML5 support, or rather HTML5 with Flash support.

I know how to get the HTML5 drag and drop working, but I can't quite figure out the mechanics of a Java Servlet connection and/or backend.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

> *I know how to get the HTML5 DnD working, but I can't quite figure out the mechanics of a Java Servlet connection and/or backend.*

It's not different from when using a regular `<form enctype="multipart/form-data">`. All you need to do is to get that HTML5/JS code to send a `multipart/form-data` request with the dropped file, exactly the same kind of request as it would have been sent with a regular `<input type="file">` field. I'll assume that you just can't figure out how to achieve exactly that with HTML5/JS.

You can utilize the new [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) [`File`](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) API, [XHR2](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/) [`FormData`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#interface-formdata) and [`XMLHttpRequestUpload`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#xmlhttprequestupload) APIs for this.

Here's a kickoff example of how your `drop` event handler should look like:

```js
function dropUpload(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", event.dataTransfer.files[0]);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "uploadServlet");
    xhr.send(formData);
}
```

That's it. This example assumes that the servlet is mapped on a URL pattern of `/uploadServlet`. In this example, the file is then available in Apache Commons FileUpload the usual way as a `FileItem` instance with a field name of `file`.

---

For more advanced stuff like attaching event handlers for monitoring the progress and like, checkout the following blogs:

- [HTML5 Drag and Drop Upload and File API Tutorial](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/html5-drag-and-drop-and-file-api-tutorial/)
- [HTML5 File Upload With Progress](http://www.matlus.com/html5-file-upload-with-progress/)

I've played somewhat around it with the following SSCCE:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>HTML5 drag'n'drop file upload with Servlet</title>
        <script>
            window.onload = function() {
                var dropbox = document.getElementById("dropbox");
                dropbox.addEventListener("dragenter", noop, false);
                dropbox.addEventListener("dragexit", noop, false);
                dropbox.addEventListener("dragover", noop, false);
                dropbox.addEventListener("drop", dropUpload, false);
            }

            function noop(event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                event.preventDefault();
            }

            function dropUpload(event) {
                noop(event);
                var files = event.dataTransfer.files;

                for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    upload(files[i]);
                }
            }

            function upload(file) {
                document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Uploading " + file.name;

                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append("file", file);

                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
                xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
                xhr.open("POST", "uploadServlet", true); // If async=false, then you'll miss progress bar support.
                xhr.send(formData);
            }

            function uploadProgress(event) {
                // Note: doesn't work with async=false.
                var progress = Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100);
                document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Progress " + progress + "%";
            }

            function uploadComplete(event) {
                document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
            }
        </script>
        <style>
            #dropbox {
                width: 300px;
                height: 200px;
                border: 1px solid gray;
                border-radius: 5px;
                padding: 5px;
                color: gray;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="dropbox">Drag and drop a file here...</div>
        <div id="status"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this `UploadServlet` utilizing the new Servlet 3.0 `HttpServletRequest#getPart()` API:

```java
@MultipartConfig
@WebServlet("/uploadServlet")
public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Part file = request.getPart("file");
        String filename = getFilename(file);
        InputStream filecontent = file.getInputStream();
        // ... Do your file saving job here.

        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write("File " + filename + " successfully uploaded");
    }

    private static String getFilename(Part part) {
        for (String cd : part.getHeader("content-disposition").split(";")) {
            if (cd.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
                String filename = cd.substring(cd.indexOf('=') + 1).trim().replace("\"", "");
                return filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('/') + 1).substring(filename.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1); // MSIE fix.
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

#### See also:

- [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824)

Comment: Hey BalusC, thanks for the answer and the bounty is gladly given, but do you know if there is a way to queue files with the new HTML5 File API, I can turn off auto-upload, but can't seem to find a way to queue the files and launch the upload from jquery dynamically... Thanks again.

Comment: The SSCCE just assumes a single file upload. Replace the `if` check by a `for` loop over `files`. Call `xhr.open()` with 3rd argument (async) set to `false`. It'll run synchronously. You'll only miss the progress bar support. I've edited the example. As to jQuery, it has as far as I know no XHR2 support (yet). It's after all just JavaScript, I don't see why the above example should be done in jQuery. Perhaps the element selectors, but not anything else. There may be already jQuery plugins for the new XHR2 support.

Comment: hox can i add custom variables to the upload? (i need this to verify the user is logged in)

Comment: This works great. However, I am using different progress bars (multiple "status") for each uploaded file. Is there a way to tell "uploadProgress()" which DOM element update (which "status")?

Comment: This helped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728750/html5-file-uploading-with-multiple-progress-bars  Although I don't like inlining the function

Comment: @user1156544: [It's just a kickoff example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You're absolutely encouraged to abstract away it.

Comment: Well, even as a kickoff example it worked nicely. The way I could reference the different progress status bars independently was by inlining the function - something like `xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e){.....}, false);` I just wondered if it was possible to use `xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false)`, but I think it's not since inside the function `uploadProgress()` I can't reference easily the different progress bars (which I can do inlining thanks to the "this" object). As usual, thanks for sharing this great example BalusC!

Answer (score -1):

You need multipart configuration such as:

```
@MultipartConfig(fileSizeThreshold = 1024 * 1024, 
                 maxFileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 5, 
                 maxRequestSize = 1024 * 1024 * 5 * 5)
```

In my case it works only with this configuration.