# Using both GET and POST

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlets

I'm new to jsp/ajax as you can see.
In a jsp/ajax file uploading webpage ,POST is used to upload the file and GET is used to get the uploading progress(with ajax).
In doPost() file uploading(it should be "downloading" in server side?)is done and progress listener is set.
In doGet() response XML is wriitten(ajax HttpRequest is GET).
HTML tags written in response in doPost() is not shown in the browser.Redirection is also not working in doPost().
I can't do any of above in the doGet() since it'is called several times in ajax .isn't it?
If I want to show the content of the uploaded file in a different page(say a text file) how should I do? ( I mean in which method should be the redirection happen?)
What I'm currently doing is in ajax if the progress is 100% ,open the page which shows the content of the file using window.open()
Can anyone please explain the process going on(the sequence).
actually this is the code I followed is 
[ajax file uploading progress](http://www.codeguru.com/java/article.php/c13913__1/AJAX-File-Upload-Progress-for-Java.htm)

Comment: Please see the FAQ about chatty/open-ended questions and consider revising to a single, specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *HTML tags written in response in doPost() is not shown in the browser*

Perhaps you need to flush the response buffer first? This however conflicts with the statement that redirection doesn't work. Perhaps you mean that only a few HTML tags are shown and not all?

---

> *Redirection is also not working in doPost()*

This will indeed fail with `IllegalStateException: response already committed` in server logs (did you read them?) if you write and flush HTML tags to the response beforehand.

---

> *If I want to show the content of the uploaded file in a different page(say a text file) how should I do?*

Do **not** write anything to the response before calling `response.sendRedirect()` in `doPost()`. Let ajax and `doGet()` worry about handling those "HTML tags" you're talking about before.

On a related note, you may find this answer interesting as well: [HTML5 File Upload to Java Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114087/html5-file-upload-to-java-servlet/7136219#7136219).

Comment: thank you.seems I need quite a time spend on studying these.anyway is it happening as follows?1-after click on submit button doPost() method is called.2-in doPost() file is being downloaded.3-mean while doGet() is called several time and response XML is read.4-after file is uploaded what ever code at the last (bottom) of the doPost() is executed.In the TCP/IP Monitor in eclipse the last response to the browser seems to to be the XML that says progress percentage is 100.What I mean by HTML tags was the output at the bottom of doPost() which then I tried to replace with response.sendRedirect()