# Uploading a file to a perl cgi script from Javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, perl

I want to send a file to a server using Javascript on the client end and a perl cgi script on the server. And well I don't know where to start.

This is what I understand that I need to do; open the file read it, pass it to the server as the request body, pull the file out of the request body at the server end.

So any one know a good way to do this? also if I have got any of the basics wrong please let me know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 File Upload to Java Servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114087/html5-file-upload-to-java-servlet)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using jquery client-side and CGI.pm server-side. The following resources will provide details:

- [Tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) on how to exploit the File API of modern browsers (with or without drag-and-drop metaphor).
  To see whether or not your targeted user agents support this technique, look [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi) and [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader).
- [JQuery method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to issue a POST request
  the `data` attribute will be `reader.result` in your case (adopting the variable names from the code examples in the linked tutorial).
  just keep in mind to call `reader.readAsText` to make the file contents available to javascript.
- processing uploaded files with the perl module [CGI.pm](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html#PROCESSING-A-FILE-UPLOAD-FIELD) as part of a cgi script.

drop a comment if you need more support to get your job done. the explanations and the sample code in the cited docs are actually pretty good.
Also have a look at the answer to the question Quentin ref'ed if you haven't yet done so. regards