# Show a simple GIF, while uploading files with HTML5

Tags: jquery, html, file-upload, progress-bar, gif

Using HTML5 to upload a file, is it possible to check if a file is uploading? 
Eventually I would like to show a simple gif like a progress bar, but without any 
dificult counters/mathematic, so just a simple gif like this;

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/DFT78/

And when the file is uploaded I want this to hide again. What I would like to know is;
How can I 'check' if a file is uploading?

**Code** (HTML5rocks)

```
    <style>
  .thumb {
    height: 75px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 10px 5px 0 0;
  }
</style>

<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>

<script>
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

      // Only process image files.
      if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
        continue;
      }

      var reader = new FileReader();

      // Closure to capture the file information.
      reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
          // Render thumbnail.
          var span = document.createElement('span');
          span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                            '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
          document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
        };
      })(f);

      // Read in the image file as a data URL.
      reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8858040/405398 & use XHR's progress event.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the "correct" way to do this. But I use an Iframe to the upload page and then I can place a gif in there while the upload is working.